# Credit Card Verification Problems with char parsing

Tags: java, char, jframe

I was working on a group project that asks us to determine if a credit card is legitimate or not. I was able to find some links where I got an algorithm. To sum that up, if the final sum is divisible by 10, the credit card number is valid. If it's not divisible by 10, the number is invalid or fake! I have one main problem.

EDIT: the setSize() method doesn't work properly. It won't accept the dimensions I need to feed it

```
public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private Dimension d = new Dimension(500, 300);
    private JPanel panel1, panel2;
    private JButton test, reset;
    private JLabel instructions;
    private JTextField text;


    public Main(){
        setTitle("****Credit Card Test****");
        setSize(d);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setSize(this.getWidth() , this.getHeight());
        panel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); 

        instructions = new JLabel("Enter a Creit Card number-------");
        test = new JButton("Test");


        reset = new JButton("Reset");
        text = new JTextField();

        addItem(panel1, instructions, 0, 0, 2, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
        addItem(panel1,test, 0, 2, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
        addItem(panel1, reset, 2, 2, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);
        addItem(panel1, text, 0, 1, 3, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER);


        add(panel1);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    //Good usage of static here because there is only 1 algorithm.
    public static boolean luhmAlgorithm(String num) {
        boolean bool;       
        for(int i = 0; i <= num.length(); i++){
            num.toCharArray();
            num [i] = Integer.parseInt(num[i]);
        }       
        return bool;
    }

    public void addItem(JPanel p, JComponent c, int x, int y, int width, int height, int align){
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.gridx = x;
        constraints.gridy = y;
        constraints.gridwidth = width;
        constraints.gridheight = height;

        //Sets amount of space for padding (top, left, bottom, right)
        constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        constraints.anchor = align;//(CENTER, NORTH, NORTHEAST, EAST, SOUTHEAST, SOUTH, SOUTHWEST, WEST, NORTHWEST)
        //Stretch components to fill space (NONE, HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL, BOTH)
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getActionCommand()){
            case "Reset":
                text.setText(null);
            break;
            //Remember use colons : instead of semi-colons ;    
            case "Test":
                if(luhmAlgorithm(text.getText())){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This credit card is valid.");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INVALID CREDIT CARD!");
                    break;
                }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Long.parseLong(...)` perhaps?

Comment: Create a type for your credit card

Comment: What's the question here specifically?

Comment: @Radiodef my setSize(d) method isn't working properly. It won't accept any dimensions that i give it? And when I modify the code a little bit to get that part to work, i get pointer exception errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question pertains to obtaining the input from the user, so I am going to answer this question based on the luhmAlgorithm you provided (sum of card #s / 10):

```
public static boolean luhmAlgorith(String num)
{
    boolean bool;
    char[] numAsCharArray = num.toCharArray();
    int cardSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= num.length(); i++)
    {
        cardSum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numAsCharArray[i]));
    }
    if (cardSum % 10 == 0)
    {
        bool = true;
    }
    else
    {
        bool = false;
    }
    return bool;
}
```

In this code block, we are converting the string to a char array *before* looping (why create a char array every time we loop? It's overkill). Then, we will loop through each index, and add that value to our sum called `cardSum`.  `cardSum` will keep track of the running total, hence why it is outside of the loop.  Then, we check the modulus of the sum. If `cardSum % 10 ==0` (sum is divisible by 10), then we set `bool` to true. Otherwise, we set `bool` to false. Then we return `bool`.

However, we can refactor this code to make it cleaner.  Since we're returning a boolean, why not get rid of the `if/else` block? We can use this instead of the block to make things cleaner:

```
return cardsum % 10 == 0
```

If `cardsum % 10` equals 0, the condition will be true, and the method will return true. This one line can get rid of 9 lines of code! -- Just something to think about :)

And another note: You may want to catch a `NumberFormatException` if the user provides a non-numerical input. If this is not a requirement for your project, I would not be overly concerned.  However, it is a good practice to get into! (thanks for the recommendation Michel Michael Meyer)

Comment: I would add to this that you should replace the if statements for the return values with `return cardSum % 10 == 0`

Comment: True. However, I just realized that I can't parse a char :/

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numAsCharArray[i]));`

Comment: And I'd like to add that the `NumberFormatException` should be handled properly in case of non-digit characters.

Comment: `(int)(numAsCharArray[i])` will not return the correct answer.

Comment: Uhm... `(int)(numAsCharArray[i]);` ... won't that return the `char`-code number for each character? In case if `1` it'll return 49, won't it?

Comment: You are returning false instead of bool.

Comment: thanks for the code reviewing everyone. apparently I need more caffeine

Comment: In that case, would it be possible to use a switch block? I mean, switch each 'char' into an int? Or would that not work?

Comment: I'm not sure how a `switch` would be more beneficial than a loop. Why are you thinking of using a `switch` statement?

Comment: I suggest the switch because someone commented that `(int)(numAsCharArray[i])` would return the ASCII or "char" value. If that's  true, i could use a switch block to convert the values from ASCII to base 10 right away...

Comment: I changed my answer to remove `(int)(numAsCharArray[i])` to fix that issue. Having a `switch` would be extra lines (one for each possible char value)

Comment: It does return the ASCII value, but it returns 49 for 1 and 50 for 2 and so on, You would have to do (int)(numsCharArray[i] - 48 for each number. Even then you don't need a switch statement. But using the Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(...)) does all that work for you. Don't try to reinvent the wheel and make your problem more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @mdewitt that makes a lot more sense now. Thank you so much for all the help!!

Comment: Not a problem! Glad we could help